# How to handle initialization failure when there are multiple servlets in a webapp

Tags: java, servlets

My particular setup is a Java webapp packaged as a war file under Tomcat7, but the question is more general. In our webapp, we have multiple servlets being registered via the Servlet 3.x @WebServlet annotation (and also marked loadOnStartup=1). The question is what to do if one of the servlets fails for some legitimate reason during initialization by throwing an exception. In this case, we're seeing two issues:

1. Tomcat notices that the servlet failed. But our service keeps getting probed by a load balancer trying to decide whether to include us in the pool. Every probe is an access to a URL mapped to the servlet that failed. Tomcat keeps trying and retrying to initialize the webapp, failing each time. Is there a way to cause Tomcat to just stop trying and give up? We can monitor for initialization failure and take corrective action if required.
2. The other servlets in the same webapp did not fail (those are also loaded via a WebServlet annotation with loadOnStartup=1). So if we try to access them by hitting an appropriate URL, Tomcat lets us through. We would prefer it if the failure of one servlet in the webapp would cause the whole webapp to fail.

Comment: What is the purpose of using initialization in your servlets? Are you trying to load data to use as cache or something similar?

Comment: Yes. Actually I am presenting a simplified picture, the main initialization is done in a Jersey Application class which initializations connctions to external services and caches some things, but if it fails, that fails the main Jersey servlet. The other servlets expose ancillary things like metrics and healthchecks that are not part of the main API.

Comment: Then wero's approach is the right to follow.

Answer (score 4):

You could place all failable startup operations in a `ServletContextListener` which is initialized before any servlet. If the init of the `ServletContextListener` fails the whole webapp is not deployed.

Your servlets could then in their initialization simply ask the singleton `ServletContextListener` for their already initialized resources.

Comment: Thanks, I was grasping for something like that, but your approach seems like the right thing to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

1. Put all startup operation code in the `ServletContextListener`.
2. At the end of all start up operations, put an attribute (`true or false`) in the context `context.setAttribute()`. Or put several `T/F` attributes for different init operation results.
3. Add a filter for this `servlet` to handle all requests. Check the context attribute, if startup operation failed, this filter will gracefully respond to the request, either by redirect or send error respond code to load balancer query.